# Проверка условия на попадания в диапазон

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Задача следующая, у меня есть некий dataframe по ценам на акции.
Я нашел скользящею среднею по 100 дней, теперь надо проверить: если это значение попадает в диапазон от 0 до х10 от ежедневного объема то присваиваю значения истина, в противном случае, лож

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

excel_file = pd.ExcelFile('ABVG.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(io='ABVG.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df = df.drop(columns='Комментарий')


Long = 100
df['LMA'] = df['Volume'].rolling(Long).mean()
df = df.fillna(0)

           Date       Volume    Open    High     Low   Close  Adj Close     LMA
0    2021-05-03   68303969.0  0.0004  0.0004  0.0003  0.0003     0.0003     0.0
1    2021-04-30   71543631.0  0.0003  0.0004  0.0003  0.0003     0.0003     0.0
2    2021-04-29   68309894.0  0.0004  0.0004  0.0003  0.0003     0.0003     0.0
3    2021-04-28  128170551.0  0.0004  0.0004  0.0003  0.0003     0.0003     0.0
4    2021-04-27  313368602.0  0.0004  0.0004  0.0003  0.0004     0.0004     0.0
...         ...          ...     ...     ...     ...     ...        ...     ...
4998 2001-06-19          0.0  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300     3.3300  2892.5
4999 2001-06-18          0.0  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300     3.3300  2892.5
5000 2001-06-15          0.0  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300     3.3300  2892.5
5001 2001-06-14          0.0  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300     3.3300  2853.5
5002 2001-06-13       1800.0  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300  3.3300     3.3300  2871.5
```

Comment: какое значение? чему присваиваю? Как может значение цены попадать в диапазон от объема?

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну, есть же метод определения разворота рынка по соотношениям объема торгов, а это его секретная модификация:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вот такое будет условие:

```py
df['flag'] = (0 <= df['LMA']) & (df['LMA'] <= df['Volume'] * 10)
```

Основная тонкость при использовании множественных условий в `Pandas` - нужно с ними работать с помощью битовых функций и обязательно брать условия в круглые скобки.

Comment: Немножко не то выводит, но логику понял, огонь, спасибо большое

Comment: @КириллАщепов Да, я тупанул, у вас одно верхнее только условие нужно ))  Ой, или я опять не так прочитал. Что-то туплю сегодня напрочь... Вроде теперь должно быть правильно )

Comment: А можешь помочь немного по этой же теме? @CrazyElf

Comment: @КириллАщепов Я видел тот вопрос, может завтра, спать тоже надо же ))

Comment: Хорошо, надеюсь спешимся, только начал изучать data saitce, пока сложно идет,СпасиБО)